# Creating a put (update) method on modal in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, fetch-api

I'm currently working on the update method on reactjs however its not working on my modal. I don't know which part I got it wrong. Please help me; I'm so lost...

This part of the code is where the modal is:

```
<div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
         <div className="modal-dialog">
           <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Update Employee</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="container">
          <form name="Employee" className="form-horizontal" onSubmit={this.handleSubmitUpdate}>
            <div className="modal-body">
              
                <table> 
                <tbody>
                
                <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" 
                       value={this.state.Employee_Name} 
                       onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                       name="Employee_Name"
                       /> 
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>
                <input type="text"
                       value={this.state.Address} 
                       onChange={this.handleAddressChange}
                       name="Address"
                       />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Department</td>
                <td>
                <input type="text"
                       value={this.state.Department} 
                       onChange={this.handleDepartmentChange}
                       name="Address"
                       />
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
             </form>  </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
            <botton className="btn btn-info"  id="employee_submit" onclick={this.handleSubmitUpdate.bind(this,this.state.Employee_ID)}> Update Employee</botton>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
```

and this part is where the code for put fetch however its now working I don't know which part of the code is not working:

```
handleOnclick(id,name,address,department) {


 this.setState({
    Employee_ID : id,
    Employee_Name: name,
    Address: address,
    Department: department,
  });
  }
}

const Form = React.createClass({

handleSubmitUpdate(data) {
        Employee (this.state.Employee_Name, data);
        Employee (this.state.Address, data);
        Employee (this.state.Department, data);
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.setState(props);
    }
export function Employee(id, data) {
  debugger
         return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PutEmployeeDetail/'+ id, {
        method: 'PUT',
        mode: 'CORS',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        return res;
    }).catch(err => err);
```